# Google Sheet Script: TypeError: Cannot find function newFilterCriteria in object Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-macros

With the Macro I want to Copy data from one sheet to another. The purpose of the script is to recognize the Project ID that is selected, set a filter in the other sheet so only the rows with the specific Project ID are copied.

I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function newFilterCriteria in object Spreadsheet.

```
function CopyData() {

  //Counting variable i
  var i = 1;

  //Array with all PID´s
  var HideValues = [0,1];

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  //Set active sheet to Visualization
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Visualization'), true);

  //Variable with selected PID
  var SelectedPID = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('C1').getValue();

  //Set active sheet to PID
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('PID'), true);

  //Variables with row and column to go through all PID´s
  var row = 2;
  var col = 1;

  var rowCheck = 2;
  var colCheck = 3;

  var isSelected = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(rowCheck, colCheck  ).getValue();

  //Add all PID´s to an array
  while (i < 500) {
    if (isSelected == 0){
      HideValues.push(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, col  ).getValue());
      i++;
      row++;
      rowCheck++;}
    else {
      i++;
      row++;
      rowCheck++;}}

  //Set active sheet to TEM Tool Data
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TEM Tool Data'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'TEM Tool Data\'!E1').activate();
  var criteria = spreadsheet.newFilterCriteria(); 

  //Remove all PID´s from the filter
  while (i<500){
  criteria.setHiddenValues([HideValues[i-1]])
  .build();
  i++;}  

  //Add selected PID to the filter
  //criteria.setVisibleValues([SelectedPID])
  //.build();

  //Filter
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, criteria);

  //Copy filtered area
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:I1386').activate();

  //Set active sheet to Visualization
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Visualization'), true);

  //Paste
  spreadsheet.getRange('A5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'TEM Tool Data\'!A2:I1386').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), spreadsheet.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('J3').activate();
};
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, for example, how about modifying from `var criteria = spreadsheet.newFilterCriteria()` to `var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newfiltercriteria)

Comment: @Tanaike If I change it the way you said I don´t get the Error message mentioned above but I get this one: TypeError: Cannot read property "PASTE_NORMAL" from undefined.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new issue, I couldn't noticed about it. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to remove the new issue, please modify `spreadsheet.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL` to `SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/copy-paste-type.html)

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks a lot :) It worked. Have a great day mate!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: @Tanaike How can I post it as an answer? Sorry I´m new here ^^

Comment: @TimoMeyer to answer a question, write it in the `textarea` below and click on the blue button `Post Your Answer`.